# An error occur when i am trying to add primary key's data type string using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

my code is here

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('semesters', function (Blueprint $table) {
//            $table->increments('id');
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->string('semester_id')->unique()->unsigned();

            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }
```

**error is here**

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that    corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'unsigned not null, `created_at` times   tamp
>   default 0 not null, `updated_at` times' at line 1 (SQL: create table
>   `semesters` (`semester_id` text unsigned   not null, `created_at`
>   timestamp default 0 not null, `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not
>   null) default character s   et utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci engine =
>   InnoDB)

Comment: don't you mix type ? `string` VS `unsigned`? try just change to `$table->integer('semester_id')->unique()->unsigned();`
to

Comment: i want string data type to my primary key

Comment: so remove `->unsigned();` part then

Comment: thank you this work for me :)

Comment: @muhammadarslan, if it works for you, you should accept Alex's answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mix types: `string` and `unsigned` (which is **int**)

So if you need this column to be a string you should get rid of `unsigned part` here:

```
 $table->string('semester_id')->unique()->unsigned(); <---
```

so that line becomes:

```
 $table->string('semester_id')->unique();
```